# What are the jars of red and blue liquid in sickbay?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

Throughout *Star Trek: The Next Generation*, jars of red and blue liquid are often seen in sickbay, like in this screenshot from *Evolution*:

[image: Jars of red and blue liquid in the Enterprise's sickbay, from the episode ‘Evolution’]

What *are* they?

Comment: I believe they are jars of liquid: one red in color, the other, blue.

Comment: @Politank-Z: You’re just throwing away reputation points by not making that an answer!

Comment: @Politank-Z: alternatively: thank you Mister Data.

Comment: Laughs are better then rep anyway :-)

Comment: They're the raw essences of the red and blue pills. Drink the blue one and you wake up in your quarters. Drink the red one and you wake up in a Borg alcove to be picked up by the Unimatrix Zero rebels.

Comment: The blue is Romulan ale. The red is rosé.

Comment: Joke's on you, they're both the same thing with a different light underneath.

Comment: https://youtu.be/kG-0V-85H_0?t=1m39s

Comment: Whatever they are, they were using them to store android body parts in; http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/observations/datalore/08-datalore.jpg.

Comment: Probably the same as the bottles of colored liquids I'm pretty sure I remember seeing in the TOS sickbay.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite : I kinda get the feeling you're rewatching *TNG*...

Comment: @Richard: good lord yes. Maybe the red ones are for human body parts?

Comment: @AnthonyX: pics or it didn’t happen.

Comment: @Praxis: you, sir, have made an astute observation.

Comment: Something to ponder on...but does anyone think that the blue liquid might have been included because.. Babercide...https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbicide

Comment: Health and mana?

Comment: The stuff that comes out of the GNDN pipes?

Comment: Could it be lemonade?

Comment: My first thought was Healing and Mana potions.

Comment: @JoeL.This is Crusher's sickbay not McCoy's.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They seem to be the C24th take on pharmacists' [carboys](https://web.archive.org/web/20141008225215/https://www.rpharms.com/carboys--cosmetics-and-chemists/carboys---history--colours-and-myths.asp) which are a traditional symbol of somewhere you can get medicine. They only contain coloured liquid.

[image]

> The carboy is a recognised symbol of the pharmaceutical profession. It dates back to the 1600s when they were used to distinguish between pharmacists and apothecaries who used a pestle and mortar as their sign.Some historians believe that they became more important during outbreaks of the plague in the 1600s. People needed to reach pharmacists quickly and literacy levels were low, the carboys were used as a guide.

...

> Colours
>
> Some carboys are made of coloured glass and others contain coloured liquids. They showed customers the purpose of the shop when few could read. The reason for their colourfulness was to attract custom. There are many explanations for the use of certain colours.
>
> Meanings of colours
>
> The reasons below have medical origins:
>
> Blue and Red - represents venous (deoxygenated) and arterial (oxygenated) blood. <sup>[1](https://web.archive.org/web/20141008225215/https://www.rpharms.com/carboys--cosmetics-and-chemists/carboys---history--colours-and-myths.asp)</sup>

Comment: I think this is more of an "out of universe" kinda answer (not least because we see them being used on at least one occasion) but you still get my +1

Answer (score 5):

Speculation:
The red one could be Cordrazine - as McCoy is shown with a hypo of red liquid identified as cordrazine in *City on the Edge of Forever*

[image]

> Cordrazine was a strong chemical stimulant useful for emergency
>   medical treatment. It was primarily used to stimulate the heart during
>   cardiac arrest. The drug was a red liquid and was injected with a
>   hypospray. In 2267, Captain Kirk noted that cordrazine was "tricky
>   stuff," (TOS: "The City on the Edge of Forever") but by the 24th
>   century, it had become ubiquitous and was being used by physicians in
>   much higher doses than in Kirk's day.

Quote from entry on cordrazine at Memory Alpha: https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Cordrazine

Answer (score -2):

I always believed it was bio mimetic gel, it seems like a good explanation to me. You can’t replicate any complex medical chemicals without biomimetic gel.

Comment: Why do you suspect this?

Comment: Bio-mimetic gel is mentioned in DS9 but I can't recall ever having seen it, and certainly not in TOS

Comment: I thought that stuff was green in DS9 anyway